# How do I create a calendar appointment from an e-mail in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011

How do I create a calendar appointment from an e-mail in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

In Windows, the e-mail content and attachments are carried over just by dragging and dropping. Dragging and dropping on the Mac doesn't work.

Is there any other function to take an e-mail and make it a calendar appointment?

I'm trying to avoid emailing it to myself.

Edit: Since someone went to the trouble to make [email2task](http://www.email2task.com/), is it safe to assume this feature is not available otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 2011 for the Mac was re-written from the ground up (Microsoft didn't re-use the previous Entourage code), so it's lacking a lot of features that: 
A) Are in the Windows version 
B) Have been in previous versions.

But the upside is that it's fast and native on Intel-based Mac OSX.

There is no built-in feature to create an appointment from message in Outlook 2011 for Mac, so I wrote one: [Appointment from Message v2.1](http://logicsw.com/products)